# Transfiguring an Image with Multiple Tikz Shading Angles

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, includegraphics, shading, tikz-pic

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\textheight=10in
\usepackage{tikz,graphicx}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[opacity=0.5, inner sep=0pt](A) at (0, 0) {\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}};
    \shade [left color=blue, right color=white, shading angle=45, opacity=0.5]
           (A.south west) rectangle (A.north east);
\end{tikzpicture} \, Shading Angle=45

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[opacity=0.5, inner sep=0pt](A) at (0, 0) {\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}};
    \shade [left color=blue, right color=white, shading angle=135, opacity=0.5]
           (A.south west) rectangle (A.north east);
\end{tikzpicture} \, Shading Angle=135

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[opacity=0.5, inner sep=0pt](A) at (0, 0) {\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}};
    \shade [left color=blue, right color=white, shading angle=225, opacity=0.5]
           (A.south west) rectangle (A.north east);
\end{tikzpicture} \, Shading Angle=225

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[opacity=0.5, inner sep=0pt](A) at (0, 0) {\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}};
    \shade [left color=blue, right color=white, shading angle=315, opacity=0.5]
           (A.south west) rectangle (A.north east);
\end{tikzpicture} \, Shading Angle=315
\end{document}
```

which produces the four images

[image]

I would, effectively, like to combine all four images into one; that is, I would like to produce an image with the combined effects of `shading angle=45`, `shading angle=135`, `shading angle=225`, and `shading angle=315` but it seems that the `\shade` command can only handle one shading angle at a time. How may I, if possible, combine all four shading angle effects into one `tikzpicture`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know how you imagine the result of that should look like!? One way is to blend several shades. There are many blend modes - see page 357-359 in the manual.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[opacity=0.5, inner sep=0pt] (A) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}};
\begin{scope}[blend mode=lighten]
\shade [left color=blue, right color=white, shading angle=45 , opacity=0.5] (A.south west) rectangle (A.north east);
\shade [left color=blue, right color=white, shading angle=135, opacity=0.5] (A.south west) rectangle (A.north east);
\shade [left color=blue, right color=white, shading angle=225, opacity=0.5] (A.south west) rectangle (A.north east);
\shade [left color=blue, right color=white, shading angle=315, opacity=0.5] (A.south west) rectangle (A.north east);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[opacity=0.5, inner sep=0pt] (A) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}};
\shade [inner color=blue, outer color=white, shading angle=45 , opacity=0.5] (A.south west) rectangle (A.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two shaded images]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[opacity=0.5, inner sep=0pt] (A) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}};
\shade [left color=blue, right color=white, shading angle=45 , opacity=0.5] (A.center) rectangle (A.south east);
\shade [left color=blue, right color=white, shading angle=135, opacity=0.5] (A.center) rectangle (A.north east);
\shade [left color=blue, right color=white, shading angle=225, opacity=0.5] (A.center) rectangle (A.north west);
\shade [left color=blue, right color=white, shading angle=315, opacity=0.5] (A.center) rectangle (A.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Shaded image]

You can also declare your own functional shading.